# Реализация промежуточных данных в aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот, aiogram

возникла такая проблема при переходе с python-telegram-bot на aiogram.
В первой библиотеке я мог достаточно просто реализовать промежуточные данные пользователя. К примеру:

`NAME, NICKNAME = range(2)` а потом сообщении получить эти данные и уже вывести через:

`context.bot.send_message(context.user_data[NAME]`

Как можно реализовать такую конструкцию в aiogram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого у aiogram есть [FSM](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html), вот подробный гайд [на русском](https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial-2/fsm/).

Если Вам нужно что-то помощнее и интереснее, советую библиотеку [aiogram_dialog](https://github.com/Tishka17/aiogram_dialog) :)

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!